# Gulp:Error while running from Visual Studio Post Build Event

Tags: visual-studio-2010, gulp

I am trying to run gulp default task on VS 2010 Post Build Event
like

cd $(ProjectDir)
gulp

But VS Freezes when i click on Build Solution while same is working fine on command window.
Anyone faced this issue earlier or help me in this?

Comment: Are you using gulp-watch?

Comment: Jusrhysism - Yes i am using gulp-watch.Its resolved.We have to include gulp files in VS solution before using in Pre/Post build events.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:** Visual Studio 2015 now has full support for gulp, with hooks to make it much easier to integrate.

---

**Old answer:** This is because `gulp-watch` is a long-running process; it's watching files for changes, and so does not exit.

Perhaps on your post-build task, you could use something like [cmdow](http://www.commandline.co.uk/cmdow/) to fire off the task in a separate process, which should let the build "finish" properly.

Answer (score -1):

Try using **powershell start-process gulp** as your command line. You may add a specific task too: **powershell start-process gulp mytask**

Comment: Unfortunately, you will get a new cmd window where all output will be shown instead of in Visual Studio's output window... a small price to pay if you ask me.

Comment: while this spawned a new window and gulp was running, it would not let Visual Studio finish it's build